# How is wsgi application handled by apache server with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm from PHP/Apache background. With PHP/Apache setup PHP interpreter is loaded by apache module and then on every page request new worker is created that executes entire script. I've been working with WSGI applications in Python recently and it seems that Apache (mod_wsgi) server loads the entire application and keeps it alive. Then based on incoming requests executes pieces of code. If my understanding is correct it would explain why some of my objects won't execute `__del__`?

Edit:
In my case I have a wrapper class around python mysql module. There's only one instance used in entire application. It's responsibilities are to run queries and reuse mysql connection throughout the code when possible, but I have to make sure connection will be closed when everything is processed. In some parts I'm using multiprocessing where I tell the object not to reuse connection for spawn child processes. Initially I thought I can use `__del__` to implement closing mysql connection but noticed It would be never called. I did end up using flask teardown function to make sure connection is closed after each request but was wondering if there are any other options to handle this nicely.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [`mod_wsgi` developer's documenation](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading#Python_Sub_Interpreters) ... your question is answered there.  (TL;DR - yes and yes).

Comment: Relying on \_\_del\_\_ methods in Python to do any meaningful work with side effects at a specific time is a really really bad idea. Are you only using them to understand how things work. If you aren't, then I would suggest explain what you are trying to use them for so it can be explained why that may be a bad idea.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks, I updated my post to be more specific.

Comment: Read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/RegisteringCleanupCode Flask is doing the per request cleanup using something like that under the covers.